# Does the Order of Types in Google Places API Indicate Primary Characteristic of a Location?

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

I'm working with the Google Places API, and I've noticed that locations often come with multiple types to describe them. I'm curious about the ordering of these types in the results.

For instance, when querying a specific place, I might get a result like:

```json
{
  "name": "Joe's Diner",
  "types": ['bar', 'cafe', 'meal_takeaway', 'lodging', 'store', 'restaurant', 'food', 'point_of_interest', 'establishment']
}
```

In the example above, does the ordering indicate any significance? Specifically, does the fact that 'bar' appears before food or restaurant suggests it's the primary or most relevant descriptor for the place? Or is the order arbitrary?

Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am not going to re-read the entire Places API docs, but I don't remeber having seen that information anywhere. You might want to ask for clarification in the [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=status:open%20componentid:188872).

Comment: @MrUpsidown, thanks. I've looked at Google Places API docs but couldn't find what I was looking for.